# How do I fix an ANR handler throwing an exception?

Tags: android

I am debugging using an actual phone, and sometimes I am inspecting the contents of an Intent  (which naturally arrives on the main thread) in the debugger. However, since I am blocking the main thread, the system throws an ANR. Afterwards, the app crashes and I see this in LogCat:

Here is the exception:

```
07-25 12:25:32.058    673-15203/system_process E/ActivityManager﹕ Error reading /data/anr/traces.txt
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/anr/traces.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
            at android.os.FileUtils.readTextFile(FileUtils.java:159)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$15.run(ActivityManagerService.java:8926)
     Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
            at android.os.FileUtils.readTextFile(FileUtils.java:159)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$15.run(ActivityManagerService.java:8926)
```

Terminal shows that the file is actually not there. If I try and create it myself, it just gets deleted and the exception is still thrown. There is actually a different file: traces_com.foo.bar.txt. Maybe it is supposed to be looking for that, but isnt for some reason?

Comment: This is basically a non-issue, as it is from a system component rather than your app.  Focus on the behavior of your program under development, in the normal case *without* a connected debugger.  Does that have problems?

Comment: @ChrisStratton not a production issue, but it certainly makes debugging harder

Comment: Don't inspect intents with a breakpoint debugger, log the details of interest instead.

Comment: @ChrisStratton yes, that is the workaround that im doing right now, but it would be better if I could fix the real issue and use the debugger.

Comment: Avoiding clicking anything while the debugger has it stopped might help, but generally I'd recommend not using the breakpoint debugger as your primary tool, in Android *or any other system* where events can keep arriving while you are trying to study it.